# PHP - Dynamic Bitcoin transaction fees

Tags: php, bitcoin

So I've been doing research on transaction fees in Bitcoin, and essentially what I've gathered is that a 0.0001BTC fee is required for every 1KB of data in the transaction.

In PHP, using a Bitcoin API, how would I calculate the size of a transaction in order to determine the required fee?

I'm familiar with the `settxfee` option in the bitcoin-cli, and assume I'd be using that to set the fee for the transaction once the size is calculated.

The Bitcoin API in question is [EasyBitcoin-PHP](https://github.com/aceat64/EasyBitcoin-PHP)

Comment: The essential question is weather the settxfee sets the fee per KB or per transaction...

Answer (score -1):

EasyBitcoin-PHP is a *very* thin wrapper over the [Bitcoin JSONRPC-over-HTTP API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list). It provides nothing that isn't already available via that API, and of course the functionality you want isn't there. This is something you would have to write yourself if you wanted it.